# A linear transformation $T$ is defined by $T(x_1, x_2)$ Find the image of the line that passes through the origin and point $(1,-1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I know the definition of a linear transformation, but I am not sure how to turn this word problem into a matrix to solve:

$T(x_1, x_2) = (x_1-4x_2, 2x_1+x_2, x_1+2x_2)$

**Find the image of the line that passes through the origin and point $(1, -1)$.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line passing through the origin and $(1, -1)$ is the set of points of the form $(t, -t)$ with $t\in\mathbb R$ (I suppose you are implicitly working over the reals).
We compute $$T(t,-t)=(t-4t,2t+t,t+2t)=(-3t,3t,3t).$$ That describes the line in 3D space through the origin and $(3, -3, -3)$ (or equivalently one can use $(1, -1, -1)$ as second point)

Comment: Where did you get -3t, 3t, and 3t from?

Comment: What about the use of matrices?

Comment: I think my study guide is looking for a more specific answer...

Comment: Rather, I don't see why you combine $x_1$ and $x_2$ into t.

Comment: @LearningPython: Hagen wasn’t doing anything at all with $x_1$ and $x_2$ when he introduced $t$: he was describing the line through the origin and the point $\langle 1,-1\rangle$. Then he described what $T$ does to the points on that line: it sends them to the set of points of the form $s\langle 1,-1,-1\rangle$, where $s$ can be any real number.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: A linear transformation sends straight lines to straight lines. If $T$ sends the origin and the point $\langle 1,-1\rangle$ to the points $P$ and $Q$, it must send the line through the origin and the point $\langle 1,-1\rangle$ to the line through $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: What about the use of a matrix? How would I set this up?

Comment: @LearningPython: I wouldn’t use matrices for this problem: they just get in the way. The matrix representing $T$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1&-4\\2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$, but having it doesn’t make anything easier.

Comment: Ok, would you say that Hagen is correct?

Comment: @LearningPython: Sure: he just did in more detail what I suggested you do in my hint.